# codeigniter Database class JOIN USING

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how can i use 
`left JOIN Table2 using(table.id)` ?

Example of my CODE

```
$this->db->select('visits.*,patients.name,workers.dr_name,time(visits.time)');
$this->db->from('visits');
//The next join = LEFT JOIN workers ON visits.worker_id=workers.worker_id
$this->db->join('workers','visits.worker_id=workers.worker_id','left');//WORKING
//The next join = JOIN `patients` ON patient_id --> i want it JOIN patients USING(patient_id)
$this->db->join('patients','patient_id','USING');//NOT WORKING
```

i searched every were, yet couldnt find a solution, and so i opened and tried to edit JOIN function in db_active_rec.php

/system/database/DB_active_rec.php

and found the join function

```
public function join($table, $cond, $type = '')
    {
        if ($type != '')
        {
            $type = strtoupper(trim($type));

            if ( ! in_array($type, array('LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT OUTER', 'RIGHT OUTER')))
            {
                $type = '';
            }
            else
            {
                $type .= ' ';
            }
        }

        // Extract any aliases that might exist.  We use this information
        // in the _protect_identifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
        $this->_track_aliases($table);

        // Strip apart the condition and protect the identifiers
        if (preg_match('/([\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/', $cond, $match))
        {
            $match[1] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[1]);
            $match[3] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[3]);

            $cond = $match[1].$match[2].$match[3];
        }

        // Assemble the JOIN statement
            $join = $type.'JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE).' ON '.$cond;  


        $this->ar_join[] = $join;
        if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
        {
            $this->ar_cache_join[] = $join;
            $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'join';
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

tried to edit the part under "// Assemble the JOIN statement" and put ifcondition to detect USING and then adjust the query accordingly but failed.. **epic fail**

can any one help ? how can i edit this function so that it would use USING in Join query  ?

Comment: You opened the active record php file but didn't think to check the manual?

Comment: @John,,there is NO JOIN USING() in THE MANUAL nor the active record.php ther is only JOIN ON in both.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

```
$this->db->join();
```

Permits you to write the JOIN portion of your query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces: 
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Multiple function calls can be made if you need several joins in one query.

If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer.

```
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left');

// Produces: LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Comment: yp i got this. my question is how to use Join comments USING(comments.id) only , without using Join On,